# ¿Como guardar una imagen en SQLServer 2014 desde Java usando JPA?

Tags: java, java-swing, jpa

Estoy tratando de guardar una imagen que se seleccionar desde una interfaz de usuario utilizando el siguiente código:

```
private void botonSeleccionarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:       
    JFileChooser escogerArchivo = new JFileChooser();
    if (escogerArchivo.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        archivo = escogerArchivo.getSelectedFile();
        ImageIcon temporal = new ImageIcon(archivo.getAbsolutePath());
        ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(temporal.getImage().getScaledInstance(
                this.etiquetaFoto.getWidth(),
                this.etiquetaFoto.getHeight(),
                Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        this.etiquetaFoto.setIcon(imagen);
        this.setArchivo(archivo);
    } 
}
```

En donde al final, hago un setArchivo(), para que la imagen seleccionada se guarde en un parámetro de la clase llamado archivo, de tipo File. El problema es que no encuentro una forma razonable de almacenar ese archivo en SQL. En SQl cuento con una columna llamada imagen de tipo image y entiendo que se guardar en formato de byte[], pero, ¿de qué manera consigo los bytes del archivo seleccionado y de que manera leería los bytes de SQL para mostrarlo en la misma interfaz?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que hice hace un tiempo y me funciona correctamente. Este es para MySQL. Pero puedes adaptarlo a cualquier base de datos.

```
    public void guardar_imagen_BD(Connection con, String archivo){

            File imagen = null;
            PreparedStatement preparado = null;
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            String nombre_archivo=null;

    try {

            imagen =  new File(archivo);

            if(imagen.getName().substring(0, imagen.getName().length()-4).length()<=2){//si tiene el nombre dos caracteres o menos se le inventa uno automatico
                    nombre_archivo="auto"+Math.random();}//se genera un rombre aleatorio
            else   { nombre_archivo=imagen.getName().substring(0, imagen.getName().length()-4);}//se mantiene el nombre real

            fis = new FileInputStream(imagen);
            preparado = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO control_de_estudio.fotos VALUES (?,?)");
            preparado.setString(1, nombre_archivo);
            preparado.setBinaryStream(2, fis,(int)imagen.length());
            preparado.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(imagenes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(imagenes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }finally{
            try {
                 con.close();
                 fis.close();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(imagenes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(imagenes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        }

}
```

Recuerda declarar el campo de la imagen tipo Blob en la base de datos.